# SELECT/COUNT column with case insensitive values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB column that contains values which may match each other when their case is not checked:

```
my_column
---------
foo
bar
BAR
baz
```

The column definition looks like this:

```
[my_column]   NVARCHAR (15)   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL
```

When I select like this:

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table ORDER BY my_column;
```

... I can see all the results, but I just want to see the values that are duplicates when `LOWER()` is applied to all values, along with a count of how many dupes there are. So my ideal result would be something like:

```
my_column | count
----------+-------
 bar      |  2
```

I'm assuming `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` is required here, but I'm not sure how you tell SQL to "find all things that match *themselves* when made lowercase".

Comment: do you need a separate count of bar & BAR?

Comment: no @AayQue -  if BAR and bar appear, they are considered a duplicate and I want to show a count of 2 to represent those two occurrences.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to explore the different collation settings available to you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms144250(v=sql.105)
Additionally ,SQL server defaults to case-insensitive - is it necessary for you to enable case sensitivity for the whole database?

Comment: Using a function will cause any index you have on that column to be ignored. Are you able to change the collation on that table? Or do you need to use a case-sensitive collation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
  ( 
     my_column VARCHAR(25) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @tbl 
VALUES      ('foo'), 
            ('bar'), 
            ('BAR'), 
            ('baz') 

SELECT Lower(my_column) AS my_column, 
       Count(*)         AS count 
FROM   @tbl 
GROUP  BY Lower(my_column) 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Returns:

```
my_column   count
bar         2
```

Comment: ahhh the `count(*)` was the missing link. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT Lower(my_column), 
       Count(*) 
FROM   my_table 
GROUP  BY Lower(my_column) 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try thiS:

```
SELECT 
    my_column,
    count(*) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        lower(my_column) as my_column 
    FROM 
        my_table
) as t
ORDER BY 
    my_column
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Lower(my_column) AS my_column, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   my_table 
GROUP  BY Lower(my_column) 
HAVING Count(Lower(my_column)) > 1;
```

Comment: This is a case-sensitive collation, so this won't return matches for 'BAR' and 'bar'.

Comment: i don't know how to attach my screen shot here. Above query should work in all cases, I have tested in my local.

Comment: mysql> select * from employee;
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| employee_id | employee_name | employee_salary |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|           1 | Virat Kholi   |             100 |
|           2 | Suresh Raina  |             200 |
|           3 | virat kholi   |             200 |
|           4 | VIRAT KHOLI   |             200 |
+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: mysql> select employee_name, count(employee_name) from employee group by employee_name having count(employee_name) > 1;
+---------------+----------------------+
| employee_name | count(employee_name) |
+---------------+----------------------+
| Virat Kholi   |                    3 |
+---------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)\

Comment: @Shawn have you tested this query. It will work for all cases. I have shared the results, please look into it.

Comment: Will the counts show correctly for case-sensitive collation?

Comment: @Shawn yes count value is correct. If we want to show the column in lower case we need to add lower to selected column will be **select lower(employee_name), count(employee_name) from employee group by employee_name having count(employee_name) > 1**;

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1a50b/4  <<< Because of collation, to the database, `bar` and `BAR` are different. Default is case-insensitive, but the OP has a deliberate case-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly fine for me

```
declare @my_table table(
my_column NVARCHAR (15)   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NULL
)

insert into @my_table(my_column)
select 'foo'
union all
select 'BAR'
Union all Select 'bar'
Union all select 'BAZ'
Union all select 'foo'


select lower(my_column) as my_column, count(*) as count from @my_table
    group by lower(my_column)
    having count(*) >1
```